# Dynamic cmd.exe that uses cell values

Tags: excel, cmd, vba

I have an Excel macro to open up the shell program (`cmd.exe`), set a specific director and then run a command.

I have 2 values that change and want it to pull from a data entry cell on the Excel sheet.

This version of the program works fine, but doesn't account for the 2 changing cell values:

```
Sub mdhash()
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run "cmd.exe /S /K cd c:\5620sam\XXXXX\client\nms\bin & nmsclient.bat password2key md5 vzwPass YYYYY", vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

This is what I tried but the `cmd.exe` opens and says "the system cannot find the path specified". I did a concatenate on my sheet to shorten the code on the below to see if that would help but it didn't.

```
Sub mdhash()

Dim val1 As String, val2 As String, wsh As Object
val1 = ActiveSheet.Range("I22").Value
val2 = Range("I21").Value

Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run "cmd.exe /S /K" & val1 & val2, vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Build up your shell command step by step to see what's giving you the error. Start with `wsh.Run "cmd.exe /S /K echo %PATH%", vbNormalFocus`. Then try `wsh.Run "cmd.exe /S /K c:\5620sam\XXXXX\client\nms\bin", vbNormalFocus` and so on until you find your error. I suspect your path is incorrect.